# VS Code not showing model preview

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

I am currently working on a tutorial in Vue using VS Code. I am following along but I have noticed that the person who is teaching is able to see the data inside of the model.

For example, when he writes `v-for="hero in her"`, it shows this:

[image]

When I do this, it just shows this:

[image]

Do you know which plugin is used to be able to read the data rather than what I am seeing? I notice that his shows a little spanner next to the names, whereas mine does not.

These are the plugins I currently use in VS Code that are related to Vue.

[image]